# Issue with getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have written the following code to display an input with Javascript's alert( ... ) function.

My aim is to take a URL as input and open it in a new window. I concatenate it with 'http://' and then execute window.open().

However, I just get 'http://' in the URL name, even after concatenation, and not the complete URL. How can I fix this?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

    <body onload="onload();">
        <input type="text" name="enter" value="" id="url_id">
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="func();">
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var url;
    function onload() { 
        url = document.getElementById("url_id").value;
    }
    function func(){
        var var1 = "http://";
        var var2 = url;
        var res = var1.concat(var2);
        alert(var2);
        //window.open(res);
    }
    </script>

    </head>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried by passing some static url to value of input field and then checked there are  no issue related.Its showing whole url in alert for "res" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have given solutions, and you already have accepted one. But none of them have told you what is *wrong* with your code.

Fristly, you have a `body` element ***inside*** your `head` element. This is invalid markup. Please correct it:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- this is a script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // javascript code
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- this is an inline script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // javascript code
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Secondly, you need to have an idea about the execution order of JavaScript inside browser windows. Consider this example:

```
<html>
<body onload="alert('onload')">
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<script type="text/javascript" >
alert('inline');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which `alert` do you thing will get executed first? See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Krumia/SUG8H/).

So as you can see, inline JavaScript will be executed first, and then the browser will call whatever code is in `<body onload=`.

Also, `onload` function is called immediately after the page is loaded. And user has not entered anything when the function is executed. That is why you get `null` for `url`.

```
function func()
    var url = document.getElementById("url_id").value;
    var fullUrl = "http://".concat(url);
    alert(fullUrl);
    // or window.open(fullUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be calling it in `onload()`, only after the user has entered the url into the input field. Of course its an empty string, because you assign `url` to the value of `#url_id` before the user has a chance to enter anything when you place it in `onload()`.

```
function func(){
    var var1 = "http://";
    url = document.getElementById("url_id").value;
    var var2 = url;
    var res = var1.concat(var2);
    alert(var2);
    //window.open(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not concatenating with a `String` but with an `Object`. Specifically an `HTMLInputElement` object.

If you want the url from the text input, you need to concatenate with `url.value`.

Comment: Concatenation is working, even without conversion to String.
Is there a function to find out the data type of an object in Javascript?

Comment: You can use `typeof`, like `typeof url` or even `instanceof` like `url instanceof Object` but I'd recommend `typeof` or even better test against a regex or do a string comparison, just to be sure it isn't malformed either.

Answer (score 0):

if its not concatenating, use:

`var res = val1+val2.value;`